# Excel ActiveX object creation fails in Task Scheduler

Tags: excel-2007, scheduled-tasks, activexobject

I am migrating some scheduled tasks from one Server 2008 R2 64 bit to another.  One task is failing on the new server with the error
"Reason for failure: System.Exception: Cannot create ActiveX component.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject(String ProgId, String ServerName)".

That task fails ONLY when run from the task scheduler, and not when run from the command line.  I have added the folder C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop, and the user running the task is a local administrator.

Excel is installed on the server - the program is manipulating a spreadsheet.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated, thank you!
Dan

Comment: First try to logon with the user you are running the task with and launch Outlook so that the profile will be created. Then try to use option "Run with highest privileges". In my case this was causing the problems. Strange is some task executing the same procedures were running just fine and some fall with this kind of error. But this solved the problem.